How to modify URL of an existing QgsVectorTileLayer and retrieve visible tiles in PyQGIS
I am developing a plugin in PyQGIS that involves creating a QgsVectorTileLayer using a URL in XYZ format, which points to a local vector tiles server (in this case, a PG_tile_serv).
Creating the vector tiles layer is straightforward. However, once the layer is created, I cannot find a way to modify the URL. This is problematic because I need to add parameters to the URL of the vector tiles server, and currently, this requires creating a new vector tiles layer each time a parameter changes.
Is there any method to modify the URL of an existing QgsVectorTileLayer?
